# What is the difference between reactjs vs nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have just started learning `Reactjs` and I am a little bit confused between `Reactjs` and `next.js`. what is the difference between them? Both are component oriented processes.

Answer (score 25):

Nextjs lets you render React apps on the server (SSR). If you check the source code of a react app, it's quite empty, which is not ideal for SEO matters. There are [other benefits with SSR](https://medium.com/walmartlabs/the-benefits-of-server-side-rendering-over-client-side-rendering-5d07ff2cefe8)

With Nextjs, it is rendered on both the server and the client.

They can't be compared. They work together. Nextjs "wraps" react.

Answer (score 13):

There are 4 steps that occurs when you hit a website.
For **React JS** the **CSR(Client Side Rendering)** flow is flowing:

1. Server sends a response to your Browser (Page is Loading)
2. Browser **downloads JS** (Page is Loading)
3. Browser **executes React** (Page is Loading)
4. Page is now **Viewable and Interactable** (**Page Loaded**)

For **Next JS** the **SSR(Server Side Rendering)** flow is flowing:

1. Server sends **Ready to be rendered HTML** response to your Browser (Page is Loading)
2. Browser Renders HTML of the page and downloads JS (**Page Loaded**)
3. Browser **executes React**
4. Page is now **Interactable**

Answer (score 9):

React is s library for building user interfaces.

Next.js uses React. It's a framework for server-rendered React applications.

Answer (score 2):

Next.js is a library that helps you do SSR (server side rendering) with React. You can use React without Next.js but you can't use Next.js without React

Answer (score 1):

Next.js is more like a framework for react JS . As said earlier it's more powerful because of its server side rendering feature

Answer (score 0):

In both, all the components creation and packages installation are the same.

React is totally for client-side rendering.

Next.js first render on the server-side and then on the client-side so, Next.js support SEO.

For React app:    `npm start`

and for Next.js:  `npm run dev`